# function call between two components angular js

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I need to call function between two components.
This is just sample

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirmation-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'confirmation-dialog.html',

})


export class ConfirmationDialog {
  clickme() {
    alert("hi")
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-summary',
  templateUrl: './summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./summary.component.scss'],

})

export class ConfirmationDialog {
  clickme2() {
    clickme();
  }

}
```

I need to get `'hi'` alert using `clickme2()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can call method of another component from a different component using **[`Event Emitters`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)** if they have a parent child relationship or **[`Shared Services`](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)** or using ngrx redux pattern

Comment: did it help you to sort the issue